# How do I calculate the voltage at these locations?

Tags: voltage, parallel, voltage-divider

I'm wondering how to calculate the voltage on the following charts (series circuit and parallel circuit). I'm interested in the math process involved, not the answer.

[image]

I'm mostly confused about how to find Vb as I believe Va will always be 5 volts and Vc will typically be close to 0. Any help and explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky Evidently :-)

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky It is my first venture into circuits and I felt like I should have been told the value of the resistors. I'm aware these are basic which is why I'm here to learn it. All the websites I pulled up prior to posting had the resistance available.

Comment: @user18288: My apologies. Your post seemed like a homework problem, something that is frowned upon here. If you are indeed learning, then I do still recommend a good book. Electronic Circuits by Nilsson and Ridel is a good one.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky I wasn't offended by your statement; the topic is just new to me and I'm wanting to learn the subject since I plan to use it in my future. I will check out the book you recommended, thank you for the suggestion. *EDIT* I looked at some reviews on the book and many are quite negative, is this book beginner friendly?

Comment: @user18288: Absolutely. It starts from the basics. It's hard sometimes to look at reviews,but the chapters on circuits are good. Better than that is that there are so many practice examples. That's the key, to understand you have to solve many many circuits.

Comment: This circuit is called a [voltage divider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\$V_c\$ is exactly 0 since it is connected to GND which is defined as zero volts.

\$ V_a\$ is exactly 5 volts since it is connected to the positive end of a 5 volt battery whose negative terminal is connected to GND.

\$V_b\$ is at the junction of resistors connected across the battery so its voltage depends on the relative values of the resistors.  The first circuit is a simple series connection.  In accordance with Ohm's law, the current is equal to the voltage (5 volts) divided by the total series resistance \$(R1 + R2)\$.  \$V_b\$ is equal to the voltage across \$R2\$ which is found by multiplying its resistance by the current.  In this case, then, \$V_b\$ is equal to \$5/(R_1 +R_2)\$ times \$R_2\$ or \$5R_2/(R_1 +R_2)\$.

In the second circuit, the calculation is identical except that \$R_3\$ is now in parallel with \$R_2\$. The equivalent resistance of 2 parallel resistors is given by their product divided by their sum or  \$R_2 R_3 / (R_2 + R_3) \$.  \$V_b\$ in this circuit can then by found by substituting this equivalent resistance for \$R_2\$ in the previous equation.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I wasn't provided a value for resistance, so for now I'll leave the variables in there.